# Klein Bottles in the Levine traffic model

Tags: simulation, klein-bottle

The Biham–Middleton–Levine traffic model has recently fascinated me. I started learning about it on the Wikipedia Page found [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biham%E2%80%93Middleton%E2%80%93Levine_traffic_model#Lattice_space)

One way to run this simulation is on a Klein bottle surface.  When simulating a Klein bottle though, how does one choose a "direction" for the red and blue cars?  Do "right" and "down" even have a meaning on the surface on a Klein bottle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki article discusses this under "Non-orientable surfaces".  Run it as on a torus, but when a right-moving car crosses the right edge, negate its vertical position, e.g. on a 512x512 grid, when a car at (511,50) moves right it goes to (0,461) on the Klein bottle instead of (0,50) as it would on the torus.  This can be understood by looking at the [fundamental polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon#Examples) of the Klein bottle vs. that of the torus.

Comment: Thank you, Dan.  I read that part of the article several times, and I guess I was just not understanding it.  Thanks for the link as well.  I'm just trying to connect things in my mind.

Comment: Here is a way of doing it on a spherical square lattice that I think works: red cars exit to the right moving right, enter from the bottom moving up, and turn right when they hit the diagonal.